# Android multiple run time permissions for location

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, android-location, runtime-permissions

In my sample app, I am getting location from user and i am using Google Play Services and FusedLocationApi. I am also trying to implement run time permissions for location and i am looking for the best practice. I have been searching for it whole day and i found a solution like this. I have these two methods in my `PermissionUtils` class

```
public static void askPermissions(final Activity activity) {
    if (isRuntimePermissionRequired()) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, FINE_LOCATION) != GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, COARSE_LOCATION) != GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, FINE_LOCATION) || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, COARSE_LOCATION)) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                        .setTitle("Permission required")
                        .setMessage("Location is required for this application to work ! ")
                        .setPositiveButton("Allow", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                        REQUEST_LOCATION);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                                activity.finish();
                            }
                        })
                        .show();
            } else {
                if (getApplicationLaunchedFirstTime(activity)) {
                    setApplicationLaunchedFirstTime(activity);
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, PERMISSIONS_LOCATION, REQUEST_LOCATION);
                } else {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                            .setTitle("Permission Disabled")
                            .setMessage("Please enable the permission in \n  Settings>Uber>Permission \n and check 'location' permission")
                            .setPositiveButton("Go to settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    activity.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
                                }

                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                    activity.finish();
                                }
                            })
                            .show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static boolean isPermissionsGranted(Context context) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, FINE_LOCATION) == GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, COARSE_LOCATION) == GRANTED) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

And in my `Activity`i am using these methods in `onConnected` as below

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onConnected");
    if (PermissionUtils.isPermissionsGranted(this)) {
        try {
            Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            if (location == null) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            } else {
                handleNewLocation(location);
            }
        } catch (SecurityException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "SecurityException caught" + ex);
        }
    } else {
        PermissionUtils.askPermissions(this);
    }
}
```

But application keeps calling `onConnected` back to back until i give allow permissions. What am i doing wrong and what is the best practice for implementing permissions in Android ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Request location update only if permissions are granted. If not, request permission and trigger location update only if the permission has been granted, in `OnRequestPermissionResult()`

Comment: @Wizard you mean i need to cal onConnected and onLocationChanged only if permissions are granted ?

Comment: Exactly. Request location client once the permission is granted

Comment: @Wizard but these are call back methods. How is that possible ?

Comment: Are bhai, when will `onConnected()` be called? when you call `mGoogleApiClient.connect()` right? So call if the permission is granted. Hence `onConnected()` will not get called if you permission is not granted.

Comment: Got it. Thanks !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159475/discussion-between-tartar-and-wizard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See,

When will `onConnected()` be called? when you call `mGoogleApiClient.connect()` right?

So call that only if the permission is granted. Hence `onConnected()` will not get called if you permission is not granted.

By doing this, you will be requesting location updates only if the permissions are granted.